# How to get multiple consecutive words in a script with grep

Tags: linux, text-processing

I am very new to scripting and I’m taking a course on the Linux terminal. We are using Linux distribution Ubuntu. Part of this weeks assignment is that we must using `grep` and `awk` to identify an employee that worked in a certain department at a certain time in a schedule text file separated into columns.

The annoying part that is making this all hard is that the time is separated from the `AM/PM` so it’s impossible to easily grep the times because if I put `05:00:00` it will display both the `AM` and `PM` row of workers.

I found a solution for this using by simply inputting:

```
grep -i  ‘05:00:00 AM’ file.txt
```

This worked for me and just gave me the line I needed.

But the problem is I need to use this in a script and use an argument/variable in place for `05:00:00 AM` so I can change the time as needed. However, I when I try to put `‘$1’` in my script

```
grep -i '$1' 0310_Dealer_schedule | awk -F " " '{print $5} {print $6}'
```

it changed from a recognized argument highlighted in red to being highlighted in yellow.

Then when I try to run the `05:00:00 AM`, grep takes the `AM` as a directory or file I’m looking through.

Next, I tried just using `$1` without any quotation marks in the script. Then when I went to run the script, I ran

```
sh scriptname.sh ‘05:00:00 AM’
```

this also gave me the error `“AM directory does not exist”`

So I guess I was wondering if there is a successful way to run:

```
grep -i ‘05:00:00 AM’ file.txt | awk
-F “ “ ‘{print $5} {print $6}’
```

But where the `05:00:00 AM` is make it a variable that you can change the time and the `AM` or `PM`.

I’m not sure why anything with quotation marks or apostrophes turns yellow.

The goal of my script is to produce the name of the manager on duty at whatever time I enter for the variable. Like I said, the only thing stumping me is the trying to grep `05:00:00 AM` without printing all lines that contain `05:00:00` and `AM`. I want it to just print the line with `05:00:00 AM` consecutively.

Here’s an example of the document I’m grepping. Hopefully it will turn out correctly.

```
TIME    AM/PM   TELLERS     MANAGER
05:00:00 AM     J. Doe     C. Jones
06:00:00 AM     J. Doe     C. Jones
07:00:00 AM     J. Doe     C. Jones
08:00:00 AM     J. Doe     C. Jones
09:00:00 AM     J. Doe     C. Jones
10:00:00 AM     J. Doe     C. Jones
11:00:00 AM     J. Doe     C. Jones
12:00:00 PM     A. Smith   D. MILLER
01:00:00 PM     A. Smith   D. MILLER
02:00:00 PM     A. Smith   D. MILLER
03:00:00 PM     A. Smith   D. MILLER
04:00:00 PM     A. Smith   D. MILLER
05:00:00 PM     A. Smith   D. MILLER
```

Thanks for any help you guys can bring.

Edit: the document may not be divided into columns on the preview. But in the document it’s separated by columns for

```
TIME AM/PM TELLERS MANGER
```

Comment: Added some formatting.  There are some *"fancy quotes"* like `“ “ ‘` instead of `" '` - you can [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/656798/edit) and replace with simple single/double quotes where appropriate.

Comment: Also: is the text file space-separated as posted (fixed-width), or is it `tab` separated but made *pretty* for the post? (As in - paste the actual text file if you have modified in any way for the post).

Comment: *“However, I when I try to put ‘$1’ in my script […]”* – include the relevant part of the script where you show exactly *how* you use `$1`.

Comment: @ibuprofen thanks for the help with editing, this is my first post, I was able to post my first unsuccessful script as you suggested :)

Comment: @ibuprofen also, the document is separated by space, sometimes multiple spaces, but not tabbing I don't think

Comment: @shurikenprincess: To help clarify, be _very_ specific about where you use TAB characters, SPACE characters, precise quote types, and grouping symbols. This is because they all have more than one form and/or style (HTAB or VTAB; normal SPACE or NON-BREAKING SPACE; straight single/double quote, left and right angled single/double quote; left and right parenthesis/square bracket/curly braces and even angled braces), which all have different numeric character codes--and the computer (and thus, the shell) treats them all differently, for different purposes.

Comment: In the case of the shell--and grep--using certain quotation marks (single or double) and styles (straight or "back-quotes"/"back-ticks") cause the shell to modify how the arguments are processed and then passed to grep. In turn, grep has it's own rules on how to handle the different types and styles.

Answer (score 0):

Add double quotes `"` around the variable like `"$1"`, which will allow the shell to expand it whilst grep will interpret it as a single argument still

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer. This worked for the 5:00:00 read but the grep won't accept the AM after it, it just ignored it and gives me the employees for both 05:00:00 AM and 05:00:00 PM.  the problem is just that damn space between 05:00:00 and AM that's causing me issues

Comment: I think I may know the issue actually, I’m assume you’re calling the script like `script.sh 05:00:00 AM`? In that case, the spitting happens before the arguments are passed to your script, you either need to quote it like `script.sh “05:00:00 AM”` or use `”$1 $2”` to pass both args to grep as a single parameter. I’d only recommend the second if your input will always be of this form as it may cause issues if you have something else as a second param (Not AM/PM) or don’t have a second param however.

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple with Extended Regular Expression (ERE):

In your script, enter the time as 1st arg (`$1`)and the AM or PM as 2nd arg (`$2`). So you can write your `grep` instruction as:

```
grep -i -E "$1[[:blank:]]+$2"  infile
```

- "infile" contains the content you want to process.
- `-E` is the Extended Regular Expression flag
- `[[:blank:]]` represents a space or a tab
- `+` means that what comes just before in your ERE must be present one or more times.

But the above will print the whole line. If you only want the manager's name as output, use only `awk` not `grep` and `awk`:

```
awk -v time=$1 -v suffix=$2 'BEGIN {pattern_ere=time"[[:blank:]]+"suffix} $0 ~ pattern_ere {print  $5, $6}' infile
```

... assuming that default `awk` values for FS=OFS=" " hold.

Answer (score 0):

First, there are several factors to consider (I will call the shell script simply `myscript` in these examples, and pretend it has been set up to execute it as simply `myscript` instead of `sh myscript`):

Primarily, consider how the user would execute the command: Will the user type `myscript "05:00:00 AM"`, or `myscript 05:00:00 AM`, or even `myscript 5:00 AM`? That is, will they use double-quote marks to tell the command line to treat the entire thing as one argument, or leave out the quotes and treat it as two arguments? Will they always use two digits, with leading zeros as needed, or not? Will they always provide the hours AND minutes AND seconds (and also what if they do not specify AM/PM)?

There are solutions to each of these issues, but to keep it simple, I will stick to making it a requirement that they always have to type `myscript "hh:mm:ss xx"`, where the hh, mm, and ss are always two digits number (and a valid time, so `42` for 'hh' would be invalid), and the 'xx' is an 'am' or 'pm'. Note also that the "AM/PM" might be uppercase, lowercase, or maybe they had one too many beers and type "aM"...) I will make the case issue irrelevant since numbers do not have a 'casing', and anything else can simply tell grep/awk/etc to operate in case-insensitive mode (using the -i flag, as you have already done).

Using the above pre-conditons, the line you gave, `grep -i '$1' 0310_Dealer_schedule | awk -F " " '{print $5} {print $6}'` is *almost* correct. (Edit to add: By "correct" here, I mean as you provided it--there are other ways to code the same thing more effectively.) The line you *want* is `grep -i "$1" 0310_Dealer_schedule | awk -F " " '{print $5} {print $6}'`.

Note that the difference is the type of quote marks you use in different places; Both in the command line and within the script.

Here is what I made to test...

The script file is named "myscript" (without the .sh extension, because I made it directly executable), and contains (pay attention to the different quoting marks used in the different parts!):

```
#!/bin/env bash
grep -i "$1" data.txt | awk -F " " '{print $5} {print $6}'
```

I put your data in the file named "data.txt". Here is the command and output:

```
$ ./myscript "05:00:00 AM"
C.
Jones
```

Which works as you expected.

So, your only real problem here appears to be trying to understand how different quoting marks affect the different parts.

Edit to also add: Note also the info in cbhihe's post, which focuses on the `awk` side of the pipe. I did not originally comment about using `awk` (or anything else) because that side of the pipe is dependent on the output of the `grep` side.

Comment: You do not need to pipe the output of `grep` into `awk`. If you are going to use `awk` then apply a rule of economy. You also don't need to set the field separator parameter with the `-F` flag. It is alread set to one blank space by default.

Comment: @Cbhihe: That is not material here. The OP posted a question trying to figure out how to do something, and gave the code they used. I simply used their code. I could come up with more variations in different computer languages to accomplish the same goal, _if_ they ask how to do _that_, or even ask for better ways to do it. But they didn't. They were trying to understand why their code was not handling spaces as they expected.

Answer (score 0):

Tried with Below script and it worked fine

```
#!/bin/bash
m=$1
q=$2
awk -v m="$m" -v q="$q" '$1 == m && $2 == q {print $5,$6}' file
```

output

```
 sh script.sh  05:00:00 AM
C. Jones
```

I have assigning

First position parameter  to variable m
second position parameter to variable q

last step using this variable and comparing column1 and column2  in file

Comment: What do variables `m` and `q` represent? If you're writing code to help others please consider using meaningful variable names

Comment: It doesn't really explain `m` or `q` though. For example you could have used `time12` instead of `m` and `ampm` for `q`, and then the code becomes more self-documenting. (These aren't necessarily the best names one could choose but it's an illustration.) It's then less about "_First position parameter_" and "_second position parameter_" and more about "(12 hour) time" and an associated "am/pm indicator"

Comment: @roaima, Praveen seems to be into "symbolic" programming. ;-)). I second your point, but his code passes, i think, except for the fact he does not need shell variables `$m` and `$q` at all within the script. He could just pass the script positional parameters direcly to the variable declaration on his `awk` line. AgaIn ... the rule of economy should apply as in this case it does not detract from legibility.  ;-)). Funny that the simple issue in OP seems to attract non optimal answers...

Comment: @Cbhihe: This site is not meant to only provide optimal answers. We could very well provide the most optimal answer in the form of a tightly hand-optimized assembly language (even across different platforms, by using something such as HLA). The site aims at assisting people with questions or problems, explaining things, giving examples (ideally, ones which a complete "n00b" could understand without being a professional programmer), and so on.

Comment: @PraveenKumarBS: I suggest that you edit your code variable names directly to provide meaningful names, such `clock_time=$1` and `am_or_pm=$2`. That adds the benefit that reading the `awk` line would be more "natural" as well. Read it out loud: "awk (flag v) assign awk variable 'clock_time' from shell variable 'clock_time' ..." is more clear than "awk (flag v) assign awk variable 'p' from shell variable 'p' ...", and avoids needing to look up "what is the purpose of shell varibale 'p'?" It is not as significant here, but code with dozens of lines/variables can be confusing.